# Deployed Firebase project is a blank page, despite firebase.json pointing to the build folder

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

when I try to deploy my react app to firebase, the url leads to a blank page (although the favicon is up).

After googling the problem the best post I could find suggested I make sure that the firebase.json file is pointing to my build folder, but it is.
And it is still not working.
And I do not know what to try next.
Any ideas?

My firebase.json for context:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Look at the browser devtools on the deployed page. If it's blank, there is probably an error in the console or network tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this on another post, but I waited to try it because it far from the  ranked answer.

Worked for me tho:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68506094/20063520