React App deployed on Firebase showing a blank screen
I have been attempting to host my react app using firebase hosting services, but am met with a blank screen. Running firebase serve works, the app renders properly. I have checked to make sure the public setting in my firebase.json points to the build folder. I have tried removing all of the firebase settings and re-initializing it, but that still doesn't work. There seem to be no errors when I run firebase deploy. The interesting thing is that the HTML content like <title> seems to be appearing.
I came across https://stackoverflow.com/a/68506094/20063520 which isn't the most upvoted answer, but seems to have been a good answer for some.
firebase.json:
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "client/build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewires": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}

package.json:
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@chatscope/chat-ui-kit-react": "^2.0.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "firebase": "^10.12.2",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.10.3",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.23.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-tools": "^13.11.3"
  }
}

file structure:
structure screenshot
I am also getting these errors on console when refreshing the web page. error messages
I am going to wait for a while to see what happens, will update this post in a couple of hours.
